# Cloud Function can't call PostgreSQL multiple times at once, unless test queries are run first

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

Edit: The answer to this was a bit complicated. The tl;dr is make sure you do [Lazy Loading](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-tips-lazy-globals#functions_tips_lazy_globals-python) properly; many of the variables declared in the code below were declared and set globally, but your global variables should be set to `None` and only changed in your actual API call!

---

I'm going bonkers.

Here is my full `main.py`. It can be run locally via `functions-framework --target=api` or on Google Cloud directly:

```py
import functions_framework
import sqlalchemy
import threading
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

Base = sqlalchemy.orm.declarative_base()

class TestUsers(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TestUsers'
    
    uuid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, primary_key=True)

cloud_sql_connection_name = "myproject-123456:asia-northeast3:tosmedb"

connector = Connector()

def getconn():
    connection = connector.connect(
        cloud_sql_connection_name,
        "pg8000",
        user="postgres",
        password="redacted",
        db="tosme",
        ip_type=IPTypes.PUBLIC,
    )
    return connection

def init_pool():
    engine_url = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
        "postgresql+pg8000",
        username="postgres",
        password="redacted",
        host=cloud_sql_connection_name,
        database="tosme"
    )
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_url, creator=getconn)

    # Create tables if they don't exist
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    return engine

engine = init_pool()

# Prepare a thread-safe Session maker
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

print("Database initialized")

def run_concurrency_test():
    def get_user():
      with Session() as session:
          session.query(TestUsers).first()

    print("Simulating concurrent reads...")

    threads = []
    for i in range(2):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=get_user)
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
        print(f"Thread {thread.name} completed")

    print("Test passed - Threads all completed!\n")

run_concurrency_test()

@functions_framework.http
def api(request):
    print("API hit - Calling run_concurrency_test()...")
    run_concurrency_test()
    return "Success"
```

`requirements.txt`:

```js
functions-framework==3.*
cloud-sql-python-connector[pg8000]==1.5.*
SQLAlchemy==2.*
pg8000==1.*
```

It's super simple - and it works! As long as you have a PostgreSQL instance, it will create the TestUsers table as needed, query it twice (at the same time via threads!), and every time you curl it, it works as well. Here's some example output:

```
Database initialized
Simulating concurrent reads...
Thread Thread-4 (get_user) completed
Thread Thread-5 (get_user) completed
Test passed - Threads all completed!

API hit - Calling run_concurrency_test()...
Simulating concurrent reads...
Thread Thread-7 (get_user) completed
Thread Thread-8 (get_user) completed
Test passed - Threads all completed!
```

**However**, if I comment out the first call to `run_concurrency_test()` (i.e. the one that's not inside the `api(request)`), run it and curl, I get this:

```
Database initialized
API hit - Calling run_concurrency_test()...
Simulating concurrent reads...
Thread Thread-4 (get_user) completed
```

It gets stuck! Specifically, it gets stuck at `session.query(TestUsers).first()`. It didn't get stuck when I ran the concurrency test outside the `api()` first. To the best of my knowledge, my code is stateless, and thread safe. So what is going on here that makes it suddenly not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77688883/how-to-connect-to-google-cloud-postgresql-database-from-cloud-functions/77692538) for the proper detailed usage of the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) with Cloud Functions.

The reason for the error here has to do with initializing the `Connector` as a global var outside of the Cloud Function request context. Cloud Functions only have access to compute and resources when requests are made, otherwise they scale down. The `Connector` has background tasks that run in order to make successful connections to Cloud SQL when the time comes where you try to connect, these background tasks are being throttled and causing your error because you are attempting to initialize it globally when no CPU is allocated to your function.

[Cloud Functions recommends lazy initializing global variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-tips-lazy-globals#functions_tips_lazy_globals-python) for this exact reason and is what the linked post above showcases.

**NOTE:** Initializing the `Connector` inside of `getconn` as another answer mentions is not recommended and will introduce more bugs into your code when attempting to scale traffic. It works because it guarantees the `Connector` is initialized within the Cloud Function request context but will create a new `Connector` on each db connection. The `Connector is meant to  be shared across connections to allow for scalable solutions and is thus why having it as a lazy global var is the recommended approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Specifically, I should be doing `connector = None` and then in my function I should be doing `global connector` then `if connector == None: # (run initialization code)`?

Comment: Yes that is correct! That will guarantee that `Connector` is being initialized when CPU is available, allowing it to be properly initialized and avoid the CPU throttling you are seeing which is resulting in the undefined behaviour.

Comment: This worked. I had to set `connector`, `engine`, and `Session` all equal to None, and then in my api() function, I had to set them to `Connector()`, `init_pool()`, and `scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))` respectively

Answer (score 1):

I may also be painting over a larger error (undefined behavior?), but if no one else ever answers, try this:

Change

```py
# Google Cloud SQL connector
connector = Connector()

def getconn():
    connection = connector.connect(
        cloud_sql_connection_name,
        "pg8000",
        user="postgres",
        password="redacted",
        db="tosme",
        ip_type=IPTypes.PUBLIC,
    )
    return connection
```

To

```py
def getconn():
    # Google Cloud SQL connector
    connector = Connector()

    connection = connector.connect(
        cloud_sql_connection_name,
        "pg8000",
        user="postgres",
        password="redacted",
        db="tosme",
        ip_type=IPTypes.PUBLIC,
    )
    return connection
```

Basically, if you look closely at the code, `getconn` is a parameter of `create_engine` - It's not called directly. With some logging, I found **`getconn` is actually called every time you use `Session()`**.

But `getconn` was using the same `Connector()` object every time. You were calling `Session()` from multiple threads, constantly overwriting this global object that was the reference for some internal state, so it's not surprising that you found weird behavior.

**Tl;dr**: Create a new Connector() every time you make a new Session!

Comment: This is not an optimal solution. You DO NOT want to initialize the `Connector` inside of `getconn`. SQLAlchemy's `creator` argument (which is what getconn is used for) as per the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.creator) is called everytime a new database connection is used, this means a new `Connector` will be used for every new connection. The `Connector` is meant to be shared across connections, otherwise your code will fail to scale as you will hit Google Cloud API resource quotas.